# print $i unles $i is less than 10. using awk or otherwise

Tags: linux, unix, if-statement, for-loop, awk

I have some data with a series of values on each line like this:

```
49.01024263     49.13389087     49.38177387  (more numbers...)
42.71585143     43.48711477     44.25625756  (ect..)
43.18826160     43.15332580     43.13094893
30.69076014     28.74489096     26.85725970
```

eventually the numbers reach values less than 10, at that point I'd like to delete all the remaining numbers in that line.

so far I have this, but its returning several errors.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i++)do{if ($i > 10.0 ) print $i ; next ; else ; exit}}' input > output
```

What could I be doing wrong?
Any better ways to carry out this task?

Comment: next time better gave some input example, which makes sense. for example,  your input doesn't have any number < 10. Also, an expected output would help you to get answer sooner too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i>10)printf "%s ",$i;else break;print  ""}' file
```

test with an example:

```
kent$  cat f
30 20 15 9 8
50 40 30 20 7 2000
100 200 300 400 5 444

kent$  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i>10)printf "%s ",$i;else break;print  ""}' f
30 20 15 
50 40 30 20 
100 200 300 400
```

Comment: Can you pls tell me what is the purpose of final print "" ?

Comment: @Mari remove the print statement and try the command again, you will see.

Comment: I know you got the `$i>10` from the OPs code BUT he said that code doesn't work and he said he wanted stop when the fields were `less than 10` not `less than or equal to 10`. I suspect he hasn't tested that edge case which obviously should have been part of his sample input and expected output. Also, your code will add a trailing space to each line, which is always undesirable and unnecessary.

Comment: Try this instead: `{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i<10) {print "";next} else printf "%s%s",(i>1?OFS:""),$i}' file`.